# Optional ifPresent otherwise call another function

Tags: java, option-type

I wrote code that works, however I had to create extra lines, is there a way to compress that in one line? The logic: take last page, perform searching function by regex, if not located, take the page before and perform searching function by regex

```
Optional<String> totalBoxesLastPage = lastPage.locate(INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOXES);
    Optional<String> totalBoxes = totalBoxesLastPage.isPresent() ? 
                                      totalBoxesLastPage : nextToLastPage
                                     .flatMap(p -> p.locate(INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOXES));
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Since Java 9 there is  **ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction)** function in Optional. It might help.

Comment: @zforgo ifPresentOrElse its void, thank you for the comment

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `orElseGet` with a supplier to call some function which computes the value if the optional is empty. If a value is present, it returns the value, otherwise returns the result produced by the supplying function. In your case you have to pass `Supplier<String>`. Moreover, your return type after unwrapping the `Optional` should be a `String`, not an `Optional<String>`.

```
String totalBoxes = totalBoxesLastPage
    .orElseGet(() -> nextToLastPage.flatMap(p -> p.locate(INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOXES))
        .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new));
```

Comment: That won't work since since the return type end up be Optional<Object>

Comment: The supplier should be of type `Supplier<String>`

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me , i was really blind by not seeing .or function

```
 or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier)

 public Optional<String> findBetweenTwo(Page lastPage,Optional<Page> nextToLast,Pattern pattern) {
    return lastPage.locate(pattern).or(() -> nextToLast.flatMap(p -> p.locate(pattern)));
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to return an `Optional<String>`, then `or` is the way. Also notice that `Optional.or` is available in Java9 or later releases.